# Facebook event RSVP with Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this tutorial to get my script working:

http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-check-status-and-rsvp-to-facebook-events-using-graph-api-fql/61/

Here is my PHP: http://pastebin.com/js5VTp5j

But I have a problem when passing the if( isset($_POST['rsvp']) ).

My $access_token become EMPTY and it sends to facebook this url https://graph.facebook.com/$event_id/{$_POST['rsvp']}?method=post&" without a token. So I can't change the user event status.

May someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Here's my url http://facebook.faver.be/facebook/event.php

Thanks a lot guys,

Jhon